# What are the duplicates that are returned by Hibernate queries for collections

Tags: java, hibernate

The [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing) for executing queries says that:

> Queries that make use of eager fetching of collections usually **return
>   duplicates of the root objects, but with their collections
>   initialized.** You can filter these duplicates through a Set.

For example if I have an `Order` class with list of `OrderLines` having `one-to-many` mapping between them. Then if I use Hibernate queries, in this context is my `Order` class called as root object? Then why Hibernate wants to load duplicate elements at all?

Please help me in understanding this, I am new to Hibernate so finding it difficult to understand the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root entity is the entity which is selected by the query:

```
select o from Order o ...
```

In this case, `o` is the root, of type `Order`.

Now if you do

```
select o from Order o left join fetch o.lines
```

and you have 2 orders, each with 3 lines, in database, then the underlying SQL query will return 6 rows, and Hibernate will also return a list of 6 Order objects. But the list will contain the first order 3 times, and the second order 3 times.

You can avoid this by

- using `Set<Order> deduplicated = new HashSet<Order>(listOfOrders)`
- adding the `distinct` keyword to the query:

  ```
  select distinct o from Order o left join fetch o.lines
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot JB for quick response :)